# Cannot place breakpoint in gdb in emacs

Tags: c, emacs, gdb

I'm trying to debug a small program I've written in C. I open up the file in emacs, M-x gdb, give the program filename (a.out). When i switch to the source file in the emacs pane, and try to place a breakpoint in the main function, I get the message "No default breakpoint address now." and the breakpoint doesn't place, so I can't debug the program. I'm compiling the program with the options gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic-errors -Werror. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to debug in gdb you have to use the -g option, this will let gdb work with your output file by adding debugging symbols to your binary

```
gcc -g file.cpp
```

Comment: More than "working with gdb": '-g' adds debugging symbols to your binary.

Comment: @PeterAjtai Also setting break with out any additional argument give the error message `No default breakpoint address now`.